# Can changes be returned out-of-order for change feeds?

Tags: rethinkdb

If there can be many write queries happening in parallel, is it possible that two change feed subscribers could see the same set of changes but in a different order, or to see the changes but not in "chronological" order. e.g. change A committed before B, but a change feed subscriber receives changes B first, and then later A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the changes can be out-of-order:

> 1. In many cases different shards have their Primaries on different
>      servers. So the messages containing changes from that shard may arrive
>      at different times to the machine hosting the changefeed they may be
>      acted on in different orders. Additionally there are some internal
>      details to how messages are handled inside each server that might wind
>      up in differing orders even on messages from the same shard. However,
>      we have logic in that system to guarantee that for a given id we will
>      always see the changes in the right order, so you will never see data
>      moving backwards in time.
> 2. In an attempt to reduce the amount of
>      network traffic on highly volatile data we have the concept of
>      squashing, where the server handling the changefeed combines multiple
>      changes to a since document into a single entry before sending it
>      along. The exact output of that squashing is very sensitive to exact
>      timing (and to caching behaviors in the clients [2]), and so there is
>      a relatively good chance that you would see different points-in-times
>      in the entries for very active values.

https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5969#issuecomment-233420705